# Creating nested lists / dictionaries in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very new to pyspark, can someone help me in implementing a simple function. 
I have a the following text...

```
(Cortez,Rafael A.,SJSU)
(Cortez,Rafael A.,SJSU)
(Cortez,Rafael A.,MIT)
(Kemper,Karin Erika,SJSU)
(Kemper,Karin Erika,SDSU)
```

I need to group these into similar clusters based on the Jacquard similarity. In normal python I would have written like this:

```
similarGroups = {}
groupCount = 0
with open(fileName) as fd:
    for line in fd:

        if groupCount == 0:
           similarGroups[groupCount] = [line]
           groupCount += 1

        else:
           for group in similarGroups:
               if (jaccardSimilarity(line,similarGroups[random.seed()]) > 80:
                   similarGroups[group].append(group)
               else:
                   groupCount += 1:
                   similarGroups[groupCount] = [line]
print similarGroups
```

Ouput:

```
{ '0' : '[(Cortez,Rafael A.,SJSU),(Cortez,Rafael A.,SJSU),(Cortez,Rafael A.,MIT)]',
'1' : '[(Kemper,Karin Erika,SJSU),(Kemper,Karin Erika,SDSU)]' }
```

Can someone please guide me on how I can implement this in pyspark?

I have basic idea on how to `map` and do basic operations in pyspark, But have no idea on how I can compare records and group them dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: One thing you could do is use your algroithm on every partition in `mapPartitions()` and then use `reduce` to marge all dictionaries.

Comment: Well, it possible to adapt your algorithm to work on Spark but it won't be efficient or scalable. From the other hand any reasonable solution would be far to broad to fit SO format. You may take a look at the recently added to MLlib LDA implementation. It probably won't fit you needs but it should give you some idea where to start.